# I am trying to make a Custom prefix command for my bot and it's not working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a Custom prefix command for my bot under cogs, but it's not working but when i put the same code in main file(which is bot.py) it works.

here's the Structure of my bot folder

My bot folder

- cogs(It's a folder)

  - Premium Commands(It's a folder)

    - Custom_Prefix.py
    - prefixes.json
- bot.py

here's my bot.py code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio
from cogs.Premium_Commands.Custom_Prefix import get_server_prefix

# Prefix and Intents defined.
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f"get_server_prefix", intents=discord.Intents.all())


# Startup message when bot starts.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()
    print(f"Bot is now running! :D\nName -> {client.user}")
    change_status.start()

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load()
        await client.start("MyBotToken")
```

And here's my Custom_Prefix.py code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json


class CustomPrefix(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"{__name__} loaded successfully!")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    def get_server_prefix(self, message):
        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefix = json.load(f)

        guild_id = str(message.guild.id) if message.guild else "default"  # Use "default" for DMs
        return prefix.get(guild_id, "!")  # Use "!" as default prefix

    @commands.Cog.listener()  # we can add event listeners to our cog
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefix = json.load(f)

# Default prefix, can be changed here only!
        prefix["Default"] = "!"

        with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)

    # Setting up Custom server prefix. When bot leaves the server.
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefix = json.load(f)

        prefix.pop(str(guild.id))

        with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)

    @commands.command()
    async def setprefix(self, ctx, *, newprefix: str):
        if ctx.guild is None:
            await ctx.send("This command cannot be used in DMs.", reference=ctx.message)
            return

        current_prefix = get_server_prefix(self, ctx.message)

        if newprefix == current_prefix:
            await ctx.send(f"Your Server prefix is already set to `{current_prefix}`.", reference=ctx.message)
            return

        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefix = json.load(f)

        if newprefix == "!" and str(ctx.guild.id) in prefix:  # If new prefix is default and server data exists
            prefix.pop(str(ctx.guild.id))  # Remove server data from the dictionary

        else:  # If new prefix is not default or server data doesn't exist
            prefix[str(ctx.guild.id)] = newprefix  # Update or add server data to the dictionary

        with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)

        await ctx.send(f"Success:white_check_mark: Changed server prefix from `{current_prefix}` to `{newprefix}`",
                       reference=ctx.message)



async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(CustomPrefix(client))
```

and my prefixes.json have just this:
`{}`